Format-Preserving Encryption with FF3 Algorithm - Minimum Length Constraints
I've built a system for format-preserving encryption (FPE) using the FF3 algorithm. The system is designed to encrypt any type of data while preserving the original format. For example, if the input is alphabetic, numeric, or alphanumeric, the output will maintain the same type and formatting:
Alphabetic Input: Upper and lower case are preserved (e.g., AEuHTYO becomes DGpDHDY).
Numeric Input: Digits are preserved (e.g., 8723221 becomes 2083645).
Alphanumeric Input: Characters and digits are preserved (e.g., AEu87-55 becomes DGp27-27).
However, I'm facing a challenge with the FF3 algorithm's minimum input length requirements:
Numeric or Alphanumeric Inputs: Must be at least 6 characters.
Alphabetic Inputs: Must be at least 4 characters.
I need to find a solution for encrypting texts that are shorter than these minimum length requirements.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest alternative approaches to handle shorter inputs while still maintaining the format-preserving properties of the encryption? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

The restrictions against small input in FF3 are for security reasons: it's required that the domain size is at least one million (in NIST SP 800-38G rev. 1 draft; one hundred in the original NIST SP 800-38G). That corresponds to "Numeric (…) at least 6 characters" since $1000000=10^6$, and roughly corresponds to "alphabetic (…) at least 4 characters" since $1000000\lesssim(10+26)^4$.
If we ignore that domain size requirement, it's not FF3, and it's bound to be insecure in the generic sense that any encryption scheme (un-tweaked or with tweaked shared between encryptions) with the same plaintext and ciphertext domains is bound to leak information about the plaintext because it's a bijection. This may be a problem or not. We'll ignore that generic issue in the following.
If we used the original FF3 rather than FF3-1, and especially if there is a tweak under control of adversaries, I see the risk of falling prey to F. Betül Durak and Serge Vaudenay's Breaking the FF3 Format-Preserving Encryption Standard Over Small Domains, in proceedings of Crypto 2017, or/and Viet Tung Hoang, Stefano Tessaro and Ni Trieu The Curse of Small Domains: New Attacks on Format-Preserving Encryption, in proceedings of Crypto 2018.

The question's requirement that digits remain digits and letters remain letters of the same case for each individual characters of a given message precludes direct use of FF3, which does not meet that requirement.
Critically: it would lower security to encrypt letters and digits separately. If we did this, knowing that Bob0 encrypts to Jsz4, an adversary deduces  that a ciphertext ending in 4 is for a plaintext ending in 0, and that ciphertext Jsz2 is for one of Bob1 to Bob9.
With the question's stated constrains, for optimum security, a plaintext of $d$ digits and $\ell$ letters should be changed into

a non-secret domain size integer $s=10^d\,26^\ell$
a non-secret template $t$ of $d+\ell$ bits telling which characters are letters and which are digits
a non-secret uppercase bitstring $u$ of $\ell$ bits telling which letters are uppercase
a secret plaintext integer $p$ in range $[0,s)$ that encodes precisely what's not disclosed by $s$, $t$, $u$. One possible encoding is to consider the digits code integer $p_0\in[0,10^d)$ in base $10$ and letters (without cap) code integer $p_1\in[0,26^\ell)$ in base $26$, and $p=p_1\,10^d+p_0$.

The actual encryption will be of $p$, using a PRP of the domain $[0,s)$ tweaked by $s,t,u$ (equivalently $d,\ell,t,u$) yielding ciphertext $c$, then re-encoded into characters per $d,\ell,t,u$. Because $d,\ell,s,t,u$ are obtained from/encoded in the plaintext or ciphertext, and unchanged by encryption, they are available at decryption without explicit transmission.
Additional characters not letters and digits would be simply kept. Ideally they and their position should be used as tweak too, so that Bob-0 encrypting to Jsz-4 does not leak what Js-z4, Jsz+4 or Jsz4 stands for.
Many Format Preserving Encryption techniques allow construction of the necessary PRP of the domain $[0,s)$. But FF3 is not a convenient choice because it restricts to $s=\mathrm{radix}^\mathrm{len}$ with $2\le\mathrm{radix}\le2^{16}$ and $\mathrm{len}\ge2$, and it's not possible to express many combinations of $s=10^d\,26^\ell$ in this form, e.g. $d=1$, $\ell=3$.
If we insist on using something based on FF3, one option is to reduce it's domain using the standard FPE technique of cycling. For example, use $\mathrm{radix}=2$, $\mathrm{len}=\max(2,\left\lceil\log_{\mathrm{radix}}(\max(10^6,s))\right\rceil)$, $s'=\mathrm{radix}^\mathrm{len}$, and build PRP $P$ over $[0,s)$ from the PRP $P'$ over $[0,s')$ implemented per FF3-1 with parameters $\mathrm{len}$, $\mathrm{radix}$, using

$c=P'(p)$
while $c\ge s$

$c=P'(c)$



with decryption $P^{-1}$ implemented using

$p=P'^{-1}(c)$
while $p\ge s$

$p=P'^{-1}(p)$



The number of iterations can be quite large for some parameters $d,\ell$ and some values of $p$. The average is $s'/s$, and for small $s$ that can be quite large (a hundred thousands iterations  on average for the worst case $d=1$, $\ell=0$, and a few times more for some plaintexts). For large $s$ this can be improved upon by using $\mathrm{radix}\in\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$ selected for the lowest possible $s'$.
I would thus not use FF3 at all with the stated requirements: for small $s$, there is this problem of many iterations; for large $s$, it's inconvenient. Fundamentally, FF3 is for the different problem of encryption of strings with every character among $\mathrm{radix}$ ones.

My problem isn't with alphanumeric inputs; I already have a solution for them. The issue is encrypting plaintexts shorter than the required minimum length. Solving it for numerics will solve it for alphanumerics as well.
For numerics, the minimum length is 6 digits. You mentioned using the "standard FPE technique of cycling" with FF3. However, I don't understand how to apply this, as we can't perform any encryption initially due to the minimum length restriction. For example, how would this work with an input like "123"

@Abdelouahed Abbad: cycling for an input like 123, you change it to 000123, use FF3 to encrypt that to e.g. 276523, then because that's over 000999 re-encrypt 276523 to get e.g. 053234, then 456175… until it gets to something at most 000999, say 000478 (it will take an average of 1000 encryptions, sometime a few thousands), and then your ciphertext is 478. For decryption, just replace FF3 encryption by decryption. It always works! But for mixed strings be sure to understand the part of my answer starting in "Critically", there is a serious security issue that's all too easily missed.
